# Blende 2.79a. Video Editing

Tags: rendering, video

After rendering an edited video the new video is about 1 Gig more than the original. Why? It seems excessive to me.
Original Video Specs: 
Frame width: 1920
Frame height: 1080
Total bitrate: 15112 Kbps
Frame rate: 59.94 frames/second
Audio sample rate: 48.000 kHz.
Video length: 12mins.14secs.

New Video Specs:
Frame width: 1920
Frame height: 1080
Total bitrate: 26500 Kbps
Frame rate: 59.94 frames/second
Audio sample rate: 44.100 kHz
Video length: 12mins.01sec.

Blender - Output setting:
FFmpeg video
container: MPEG-4
codec: H.264
output quality: High
encoding speed: medium speed
Audio codec: MP3

Ooh, Blender 2.79a

Thanks

Victor

Comment: Uhm... your new bitrate is too high. Keep it lower, about 15 Mbps (~15000Kbps) for 1080p high FPS videos. Also try to use variable bitrate if possible, otherwise action-rich scenes appear somewhat pixelated. See e.g. [here](https://filmora.wondershare.com/video-editing-tips/what-is-video-bitrate.html) for further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take some math.

```
12m with some seconds it is about 720 sec. Lets take this length. 

First video size =
bitrate * Length = 15112 Kb/s * 720s = 10880640 kb = 1360080 kB ~ 1.36 GB

Second video size = 
bitrate * Length = 26500 Kb/s * 720s = 19080000 kb = 2385000 kB ~ 2.38 GB
```

2.38GB - 1.36GB = 1.02GB!

Comment: ...thanks, just my lack of experience with this. Next time I'll try to record at 30fps.

Comment: @VictorArdila Do you see FPS in my formula?